# Comparing values of multiple datalists using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-datalist

first of all, I am pretty new to coding so sorry if this is a stupid question.
I created a datalist that contains all countries 
Now I want Javascript to check, if the user selected the same country in different lists.

How do I do that?

This is what I have so far:

```js
var inputs1 = document.getElementsByName('country1','country2','country3','country4'),
    country1, country2, country3, country4;

for (var i = 0; i < inputs1.length; i++) {
  var el = inputs1[i];
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    compareLists(this.value);
  })
}



function compareLists(country1,country2,country3,country4) {
  if (country1 == country2) {
    document.getElementById("ebene2").classList.add('showing');
    document.getElementById("ebene3").classList.remove('showing');
}else  {
    document.getElementById("ebene3").classList.add('showing');
    document.getElementById("ebene2").classList.remove('showing');
}}
```

```css
<div>
    <h3>In welchem Staat sind die folgenden Orte? </h3>

     Sitz / gewöhnlicher Aufenthalt des Beförderers: 
     <form>
      <input type="search" name ="country1" list="country">
      <datalist id="country">
      </datalist>
  </form>
        <br>
     Sitz / gewöhnlicher Aufenthalt des Absenders 
    <form>
      <input type="search" name ="country2" list="country">
      <datalist id="country">
        
      </datalist>
    </form>
        <br>
     Übernahmeort der Güter 
    <form>
      <input type="search" name ="country3"list="country">
      <datalist id="country">
        
      </datalist>
    </form>
        <br>
     Ablieferungsort der Güter
     <form>
      <input type="search" name ="country4" list="country">
      <datalist id="country">
        
      
      </datalist>
    </form>
        <br>
</div>
```

I am very grateful for any help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id attribute must be unique within the entire document.  If you want to use a different country datalist for each input, you will need to use a different id for each datalist.

getElementsByName searches by a single name.  Doesn't take multiple arguments.
You could give them all the same name, or use a class.

```js
var inputs1 = ['country1', 'country2', 'country3', 'country4'].map(c => document.getElementsByName(c)[0]),
  country1, country2, country3, country4;

for (var i = 0; i < inputs1.length; i++) {
  var el = inputs1[i];
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    compareLists(this.value);
  })
}

function compareLists() {
  var map = {};
  inputs1.forEach((i, idx) => {
    i.value && ((map[i.value]?.push(idx)) || (map[i.value] = [idx]));
  });
  // use an object map to collect duplicates
 
  // filter out only dupe lists > 1 in length
  map = Object.entries(map).filter(([, x]) => x.length > 1);
  console.log(map);

  // assign a different color border for each set of duped value inputs
  var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow'];
  inputs1.forEach(input => input.style.border = '');
  map.forEach(([, list]) => {
    var color = colors.pop();
    list.forEach(x => inputs1[x].style.border = `1px solid blue`);
  });

  /*  if (country1 == country2) {
      document.getElementById("ebene2").classList.add('showing');
      document.getElementById("ebene3").classList.remove('showing');
    } else {
      document.getElementById("ebene3").classList.add('showing');
      document.getElementById("ebene2").classList.remove('showing');
    }*/
}
```

```css
.showing {
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<datalist id="country">
          <option value="Chocolate">
    <option value="Coconut">
    <option value="Mint">
    <option value="Strawberry">
    <option value="Vanilla">
      </datalist>

<div>
  <h3>In welchem Staat sind die folgenden Orte? </h3>

  Sitz / gewöhnlicher Aufenthalt des Beförderers:
  <form>
    <input type="search" name="country1" list="country">

  </form>
  <br> Sitz / gewöhnlicher Aufenthalt des Absenders
  <form>
    <input type="search" name="country2" list="country">
  </form>
  <br> Übernahmeort der Güter
  <form>
    <input type="search" name="country3" list="country">
  </form>
  <br> Ablieferungsort der Güter
  <form>
    <input type="search" name="country4" list="country">
  </form>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without reading your code, I just wondering is it possible for you to do this:

When user clicks on one country to save that country in `commonCountries` array and then when he clicks on another country to save that country in the same array and just compare these two values from array?